# Ambiguous use of error given for overridden property

Tags: compiler-errors, swift

I have a subclass and a superclass defined in a playground that represent a Card and PlayingCard in Swift.

There is a computed property, with a getter, in Card called desc.  I have overridden this in the subclass to get this to be computed from two other properties defined only in the subclass.

This all runs fine in the playground and prints out "Ace Spades" as expected.

```
import Cocoa

class Card {
    var desc: String {
    get { return "Default description." }
    }
}

class PlayingCard: Card {
    var suit: String
    var rank: String
    override var desc: String {
    get { return rank + " " + suit }
    }
    init(suit: String, rank: String) {
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        super.init()
    }
}

let baseCard = PlayingCard(suit: "Spades", rank: "Ace")
var desc: String
desc = baseCard.desc
println (desc)
```

I then tried to instantiate the same Playing card and access the desc variable, but in a ViewController as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func touchCardButton(sender : UIButton)
    {
        let baseCard = PlayingCard(suit: "Spades", rank: "Ace")
        var desc: String
        desc = baseCard.desc
    }

}
```

This, however, results in the the following error:
    Ambiguous use of 'desc'

**Update**: When I expand out the error in the Issue Navigator, it points to the two candidates that it finds ambiguous:

- In class Card - `var desc: String {`
- In class PlayingCard - `override var desc: String {`

There doesn't appear to be anything in the help documentation that points that I'm doing anything wrong and I can't find any reference to the error online.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: I have removed the setters and made the getter purely a computed property following the comment/answer below regarding the misuse of a computed property.  However, now using this correctly as a computed property, I am still getting the `Ambiguous use of 'desc'` error.

Comment: What happens if you do `var desc: String = baseCard.desc` ?

Comment: also, do you happen to have a `desc` property on your view controller?

Comment: @Jiaaro - I get the same error if I use `var desc: String = baseCard.desc`.  I don't have a desc property in my view controller either.  See my update in my original post regarding the two candidates Xcode is trying to compare against.

Comment: cs193p, assignment #1, in Swift.  I'm working through exactly the same thing and found this page looking for help.  Stored property in base, computed property in sub.  In my case I'm getting it during some debug of the "drawRandomCard()" method in the deck class.  No help from me, but I'll come back if I figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

This may be related to the below known bug:

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/229668?tstart=0

https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/475664088412856320

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be a comment, but since I can't do that yet...

```
var desc: String {
    get { return self.desc }
    set { self.desc = newValue }
    }
```

is wrong. If you are using a computed property, there is no `self.desc`. As Apple's language guide says,

> In addition to stored properties, classes, structures, and enumerations can define computed properties, which do not actually store a value. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.

So your computed property can't rely on using itself as a stored property. In fact, it really shouldn't be a computed property in the first place.